# Redirect to custom page in case of error without using Response.Redirect(url) in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

I have a asp.net 4.5 MVC web project. In web.config, I have those lines:

```
...
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
      <clear />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/PageErrors/GeneralError.aspx?e=404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
...
</httpErrors>
...
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/PageErrors/GeneralError.aspx" />
...
</system.web>
```

What I want is to redirect a user to the GeneralError page in case of an error occurs in function DoProcess(..) on the code behind without using Response.Redirect(url). What I tried is to raise the error manually by using the code 404 (tried other numbers instead as well) :

```
public void DoProcess(..)
{
   try
   {
      ...
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      //context.Response.Redirect("/Errors/GeneralError.aspx");
      throw new HttpException(404, "Error Message");
   }
}
```

Although it did not work, if there is really no page (in case of real 404 error), I am redirected to the custom GeneralError.aspx. Using no parameter in the exception like `throw new HttpException();` did not help as well.

Why the manually raised error does not work and what should I do? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Below I tried, also did not help, saying "  might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address." :

```
 context.Response.Clear();
 context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
 context.Response.End();
```

Comment: There are many options for reporting errors to your user. Could you please clarify the desired behavior from the user perspective? Redirects in any form are very “webforms”.

Comment: Users must see the custom error page when they want to download a file but received the default error: "the file is being used by another process". And I should handle it without using Redirect(url) (or similar) codes in the backend. I don't know why you found the question unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when testing the custom messages, are you running on a local server or is the application deployed?

If you are running locally the `RemoteOnly` atrribute is your problem, as it only displays custom messages to users not running on the local web server.
Changing it to `On` should solve your problem and if any error occurs you will be redirected to your `"~/PageErrors/GeneralError.aspx"`

EDIT: To enable redirecting: 
`<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/PageErrors/GeneralError.aspx" />`

Comment: How can i change it to ON?

Comment: I am sorry for not making it clearer, use <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/PageErrors/GeneralError.aspx" />

Comment: Thank you!! @a.bajorinas

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Server.Transfer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800(v=vs.90).aspx).

```
Server.Transfer("~/PageErrors/GeneralError.aspx")
```

It doesn't change the browser's address bar. So it is more efficient if you do not know the browser to know about the error.

Comment: Thanks, but I shouldn't use this one as well. I am actually supposed to add the error page to the webconfig only and in case of any error occurs the application should direct the user to the error page, shouldn't use it anywhere else but web.config. Your advice works tho.